# Register a UIImageView on another a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have now made it able on my app to move a image around, scale it, pinch it.. you name it. But my question is, how can i make it able for the app to register when a UIImageView is at another a UIImageView?

Comment: What do you mean by `at another a UIImageView?`. Do you mean intersecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to look at the [CGGeometry Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

Specifically you should look at `CGRectIntersectsRect` to see if the frames of the two `UIImageView`'s intersect.

```
BOOL isImageViewOverlapping = CGRectIntersectsRect(imageViewOne.frame, imageViewTwo.frame);
```